# Ames Assay Confusion: Aren't the odds of spontaneous revertants too low to be able to accurately test the mutagenicity of certain compounds?

Tags: genetics, dna, bacteriology, mutations, assay-development

I am a student conducting a test with the Ames Assay.   This assay uses a strain of bacteria that has a mutation in an amino acid synthesizing operon, which doesn't allow it to synthesize its protein.  The idea of the assay states that if an exposed chemical has mutagenic properties, the bacteria will revert back to the wild type.

If I have a test chemical, what are the odds that, if the    chemical is actually mutagenic, the bacteria will actually revert back to the wild type, instead of having something else be mutated?  Aren't there so many other base pairs of DNA to be mutated, that the odds of the mutation be reversed  are little to none?  Is there something about the specific gene that makes that  area more prone  to a mutation?

As a related question, are there some  chemicals that have a  higher likelihood of mutating certain genes over others, or do all of the genes in a genome have the same probability of being mutated?